# Show nested usages in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: symfony, intellij-idea

In IntelliJ IDEA, is there a way to see usages of a method nested in other usages? 
I have a symfony2 app that has a class `MyClass` with method `myMethod()` this method is used in a bunch of services and controllers. I would like to trace all usages of this method all the way up to controllers that are linked to the app's routes. As a result, I would have a list of routes and corresponding controllers/methods that directly or indirectly use `myMethod()`. Is it possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Java, it's Cmd-Alt-H (Ctrl-Alt-H on Windows), so I assume it's the same in PHP.

It's called "Call hierarchy". So you can use Cmd-shift-A (resp. Ctrl-shift-A and type "Call hierarchy" to find it.

Comment: I think it could also be Ctrl+Alt+H on mac